# PTP error in gphoto2 running against Linux kernel 2.6.21.3

Tags: linux-kernel, debian, libgphoto2

In the hope that there is a gphoto or Linux kernel guru hanging around out there I am asking this question here.
I am trying to build a custom front end to the Linux libgphoto2 library. For the moment I am using gphoto2 to call into the library. I am running this on an Etch (Debian 4.0) VM image as my testing machine. I pulled the source from the gphoto-suite svn repository trunk and built it without problems. I just built the libgphoto2 and gphoto2 portions of the suite because that is all I need. When I try to connect to my camera (Canon EOS Rebel XTi) I get a PTP error and then a message that says "An error occurred in the i/o library ('Unspecified Error')." I found some references to a bug that seemed similar in relation to libgphoto2 scattered across several Linux distros with several different kernels. The most  recent one seems to be in 2.6.28 specifically declared to be a kernel bug by the gphoto-suite team. References [here](http://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12301) and [here](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=476355)

I have gotten this library to work with this camera before on Ubunut's Hardy Heron so I know that it has worked in the past. Since my target platform is a single board computer running the 2.6.21 kernel I updated the Etch VM's kernel to be 2.6.21.3 and got the same error.

My question then is does anyone know if this is really a kernel bug in the USB drivers that has been hanging around for some time now and is getting addressed in kernels 2.6.28.4 and up or if it is actually a problem with a version of gphoto2? Since I cannot easily upgrade my embedded design to a new kernel I hope that it is a gphoto bug. I am going to try building some older versions of gphoto in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

Build libgphoto with debug symbols (i.e. CFLAGS=$(CFLAGS) -g in makefile), then try to catch the bug in GDB. Looking at the actual code will give much more information on whether it's a kernel or userspace bug than the super-vague error message.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is a userspace bug. Building version 2.4.4 of gphoto-suite on the same VM image and then running works well. The good combo seems to be libgphoto2-2.4.2 and libgphoto2_port-0.8.0, along with gphoto2-2.4.2. Maybe the gphoto-devl mailing list will have the answer as to why.